# Problems with repaint() method in java

Tags: java, swing, tic-tac-toe

I'm new to **Java** and trying to make a simple *Player vs. Computer "Tic-Tac-Toe"* game using **Swing**. In the code I use `paintComponent()` method to paint certain components and call the `repaint()` method after the player or computer plays. The problem is that, the game freezes after the third (sometimes the second) time I click the mouse. In `GameWindow class` I create the instance of `Map` class.

```
public class GameWindow extends JFrame{

    private final int sizeX = 3;
    private final int sizeY = 3;

    public GameWindow(){

        setLocation(400,150);
        setSize(406, 452);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        Map map = new Map(sizeX, sizeY);
        add(map, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Button newGame = new Button("Новая игра");
        newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Начинаем новую игру");
            }
        });
        Button exit = new Button("Выход");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        bottomPanel.add(newGame);
        bottomPanel.add(exit);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the listener for the mouse click in the `Map` class:

```
public class Map extends JPanel {

private final int sizeX;
private final int sizeY;
private int cellWidth;
private int cellHeight;
private int cellX = -1;
private int cellY = -1;
private String lastPlayer = "nobody";

private String[][] table = new String[3][3];

public Map(int sizeX, int sizeY) {

    this.sizeX = sizeX;
    this.sizeY = sizeY;
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {

            table[i][j] = "empty";
        }
    }

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            super.mouseReleased(e);

            cellX = e.getX() / cellWidth;
            cellY = e.getY() / cellHeight;

            if (!winOrDraw()) {
                boolean playerProgress = playerProgress();
                if(playerProgress) {
                    botProgress();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Both in `playerProgress()` and `botProgress()` methods I call `repaint()` method to add new components to the screen. I can't really find out what is the problem in this code and why the program freezes after actually 6th call of `repaint()` method?

Here are winOrDraw(), playerProgress() and botProgress() methods:

```
 private boolean winOrDraw(){

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

        if(table[i][0] == table[i][1] && table[i][1] == table[i][2] && !table[i][0].equals("empty")) return true;
        else if(table[0][i] == table[1][i] && table[1][i] == table[2][i] && !table[0][i].equals("empty")) return true;
        else if(table[0][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[2][2] && !table[0][0].equals("empty")) return true;
        else if(table[2][0] == table[1][1] && table[1][1] == table[0][2] && !table[2][0].equals("empty")) return true;
    }

    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

        for (j = 0; j < table.length; j++) {

            if(table[i][j].equals("empty")) break;
        }
    }
    if(i == table.length && j == table.length) { lastPlayer = "nobody"; return true; }
    else return false;
}

private boolean playerProgress(){

    if(!table[cellY][cellX].equals("empty")){
        System.out.println("This cell is not empty");
        return false;
    } else {
        lastPlayer = table[cellY][cellX] = "player";
        repaint();
        return true;
    }
}

private void botProgress(){

    do{
        if(winOrDraw()){

            switch (lastPlayer) {
                case "player":

                    System.out.println("You won!");
                    System.exit(0);
                case "bot":

                    System.out.println("Bot won");
                    System.exit(0);
                default:

                    System.out.println("Draw");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        cellX = random.nextInt(2);
        cellY = random.nextInt(2);

        if(table[cellY][cellX].equals("empty")) {

            lastPlayer = table[cellY][cellX] = "bot";
            break;
        }
    }while (!table[cellY][cellX].equals("empty"));

    System.out.println("Bot's turn");
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: share winOrDraw() and botProgress() methods

Comment: @AndriiBugai I've edited my question and added these methods

Comment: For better help sooner post a proper [mcve], we need to know what's inside the `paintComponent()`

Comment: `The problem is that, the game freezes` - so look at your looping code. Whenever I see a while/do loop I would suspect you end condition is not working as you expect. So add some debug statements inside loop to display the value of the variable of your end condition. Also, don't use `Button`, that is an AWT component. In a Swing app you should be using `JButton`.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your Swing components directly to the JFrame-AWT-container. You should not do that. Instead you should do this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
myFrame.setContentPane(panel);

panel.setLayout(...)
panel.add(...);
panel.validate();
```

This should solve your problem.